# Если приложение удалено, будут ли деньги сниматься за подписку?

Tags: android, google-play

Если приложение удалено, будут ли деньги сниматься за подписку? Что-то нигде в доках не могу этого найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да.

Когда пользователь попытается удалить приложение, он получит предупреждение, что имеется активная подписка. Если он проигнорирует предупреждение и продолжит удаление, то подписка останется активной.

Соус:

> ### App uninstallation
>
> When the user uninstalls an app that includes purchased subscriptions, the Play Store app will notify the user that there are active subscriptions. If the user chooses to continue with the uninstallation, the app is removed and the subscriptions remain active and recurring billing continues. The user can return to cancel the associated subscriptions at any time in the **My Apps** screen of the Play Store app. If the user chooses to cancel the uninstallation, the app and subscriptions remain as they were.
>
> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html